# How to show a progress dialog on a particular view

Tags: android

Something like this:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setMessage("Loading");
pd.show();
```

will show a dialog, which covers the whole screen, making all the other views inactive.

How can i show a dialog on a particular view, like say on an ImageView until the image is downloaded. While keeping other views active.

**Example: Amazon Applicaiton**

The `Spinner/Progress dialog` is shown as a complete different view, while other views are Active(Clickable). Is it some kind of Custom View ?

[image]

**What I tried:**

I tried to keep the `ImageView` or such `view` which take time to load, in a different `Fragment` and until that `view` is loaded, a `spinner` like `image` gets `animated(rotated)`. There must be a far simple way?

I tried with a `TextView`, the white background is a `fragment` with `TextView` being animated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Custom progress you need to follow following links that helps you create what you want.

[Android Custom ProgressDialog with Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115350/android-custom-progressdialog-with-message)

http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-custom-indeterminate-progressbar-in-android-or-how-to-change-progressbar-style-or-color

[Custom Drawable for ProgressBar/ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog)

Hope this will helps you.