# Cancel AsyncTask with Progress Dialog button

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I need to cancel my AsyncTask with a button in the progress dialog.

I've created the Progress dialog with the button.
Here it is:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DSDactivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.pDialog));
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            asyncCodelist.cancel(true);

        }
    });
    pDialog.show();
}
```

I have two problems:

1. When I click "cancel" on the progress dialog is removed but the async
   task continues to do what he was doing
2. Eclipse gives me this waning:

*The method setButton(CharSequence, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) from the type AlertDialog is 
 deprecated*

Comment: already you are making pDialog.setCancelable(false); so how u can dismiss that?

Comment: Here is what you're looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7734109/4232337

Comment: @Shadow the process dialog working properly, the problem is another.

Comment: @NSimon I had already seen this. But do not think I can help, please create a button on the progress dialog.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12115431/609782 and you can set a button , where in `onClickListener()` you can cancel your task by `myTask.cancel();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DSDactivity.this);
  pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.pDialog));
  pDialog.setCancelable(true);
  pDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      myTask.cancel(true);
      dialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

And then, as my link said, create your AsyncTask and store it :

```
MyAsyncTask myTask=null;
```

and execute it like this :

```
myTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myTask.execute();
```

Comment: an example for cancelling an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

1. Asynctask won't stop completely only by `myTask.cancel(true);`

As the document states:

```
 To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)
```

[More Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

2. `setButton()` method is deprecated now for `ProgressDialog`, hence the warning. It will definitely work though.