# How to add an Image to a ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog

[image]

I tried many ways to add an image to a Progress Dialog
Please Help me.

Comment: With inflate custom view.

Comment: go for this link, you will get help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115350/android-custom-progressdialog-with-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_lay);
//dialog.setTitle("Progress");

TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Loading... ");
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
```

**custom_dialog_lay.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:src="@drawable/sms_ic"
          />
```

Comment: Yes..!! it's Worked for me..!! but Could you please tell me how to remove title of the dialog..?

Comment: @Chathura remove or comment this Line `dialog.setTitle("Progress");`

Comment: when comment this line Title not showing but it's space still there..!! how to remove it..!

Comment: How to include animating Gif image instead of this png..!!

Comment: @Chathura you can try Picasso or Glide library Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424748/5978440)

Answer (score 1):

Insert a layout which will hold the progressbar, text and imageview inside your layout like it is done below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recipe_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.example.android.bakingapp.MainActivity"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
    <ImageView.../>




</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```