# How to replace message of progress dialog with animation gif?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, progressdialog

I have a progress dialog but I wanted to replace the dialog's message with a custom animation gif displaying a file being saved to camera roll instead of showing just "saving". I wanted the animation to appear in the same location where the progress dialog's message currently appears.

```
        pdoverall = new ProgressDialog(activity,R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle); // this = YourActivity
        pdoverall.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pdoverall.setIndeterminate(false);
        pdoverall.setProgress(10);
        pdoverall.setTitle("Processing");
        pdoverall.setMessage("Saving ");
        pdoverall.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make an AlertDialog with your Gif as the view of the dialog. ProgressDialog is the basic available in the system, anything more customized will have to use AlertDialog.

**1-** create an XML layout containing the GIF view (find a good GIF library, many available out there)

**2-** Inflate the XML layout using `View.inflate()` with the first parameter as your XML layout and the second is null.

**3-** set the GIF after inflating the layout.

**4-** Use `AlertDialog.Builder()`, setting the View of the dialog as the GIF you inflated earlier.

**5-** show the Dialog and hold a reference to it so you can dismiss it after your progress is complete.

Comment: Is there a easy way to replicate the functionality of progress dialog that I mentioned in the code for the question in AlertDialog?

Comment: No. A progress dialog is just an alert dialog with custom layout

Comment: Since a progress dialog is just an alert dialog with a custom layout, I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to have all the functionality of the progress dialog within the alert dialog and just add the XML layout?

Comment: there isn't, check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115350/android-custom-progressdialog-with-message seems to be matching your goal